# what is the range of $\sqrt{6+t-t^2 }$?

Tags: functions

I have been looking at the function $$f(t) = \sqrt{6+t-t^2 }$$ and I am trying to figure out the range of this function. I have figured out that the domain is $-2\leq t\leq 3$. But i can not find the exact range of this function. it seems to be somewhere between 0 and "2.5".  Can someone provide the step by step instructions to get the range of this function ?

Comment: You have forgotten to take the square root...

Comment: $6+t-t^2= 6+\frac{1}{4}-(t-\frac{1}{2})$. Therefore, the largest it can be is when $t=\frac{1}{2}$. The smallest is $0$. Then apply that continuous functions have the intermediate value property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y= \sqrt{6+t-t^2}$ then $$y^2+ t^2-t=6$$
so $$ 4y^2 +4t^2-4t =24$$ and thus $$ 4y^2+(2t-1)^2=25$$ so $4y^2\leq 25$ and thus $0\leq y\leq 5/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Because the domain is $[-2,3]$, $f$ has a max in $t=\frac{-2+3}{2}=0.5$ with $f(0.5)=\sqrt{6+0.5-0.5^2}=\sqrt{6.25}=2.5$

Then, the range is $[0,2.5]$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $6+t-t^2=6.25-(t-0.5)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write $$6+t-t^2 = (t+2)(3-t)$$ Now, note that the maximum value of this expression can be found out using calculus, where we find the root of the first derivative, that is $$\frac{d} {dt} (6+t-t^2) =0$$ $$\implies 1-2t=0 \implies t=\frac12$$

Now, the second derivative being $-2$ is less than $0$, so $\frac12$ is a maxima, with the maximum value being $$\sqrt{6\frac14} = \frac52$$ Also, the minimum value is $0$.

Hence, $$\boxed{\sqrt{6+t-t^2} \in [0,\frac52]}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we mean the non-negative square root, the function is zero at the roots of the quadratic (the one inside the square root symbol). It achieves it maximum at the maximum of the quadratic - which is half-way between the roots.

Answer (score 1):

This is the square root of a quadratic. The maximum of a square root occurs when the argument inside the square root is maximized. So the maximum will occur where the upside down parabola has is maximum. This occurs at the vertex. We solve for the vertex using the vertex formula $x=\frac{-b}{2a}=\frac12.$ then we plug this in to get the $y$ coordinate of the vertex which will be the maximal extent is the range of the parabola. This gives $\frac{25}{4}$. So we take the square root to get $\frac{5}{2}$ as the maximum of the range. Of course the minimum of the range is zero, and that requires no further explanation as it is a basic property of the square root.

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \sqrt{6+t-t^2}$$
$$y^2 = 6+t-t^2$$
Rearranging gets us to

$$t^2-t + 1/4 +y^2 = 6 + 1/4$$
$$(t-1/2)^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$$
Clearly, this is a circle centered on $(1/2, 0)$. Since the square root is positive, we are looking at the upper semicircle, which has a range of $0 \le y \le \frac{5}{2}$